# Combining multiple javascript and css files

Tags: performance, javascript, css

Is there any plugin which can automatically combine all the javascript and css files that are used on a page? While I can combine them manually I would like to avoid them as some plugins add their scripts and css. Also different scripts might be needed on different pages so I do not want to have one large script on every page. I am not looking for gzipping, minifing or cache-control as I already have them implemented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

W3 Cache will do this for you

Comment: W3 Total Cache is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I use WP-Minify. It's good too.